# Get web directories with "403 Forbidden" block

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to view a web directory. It only works when I enter "folder/images/cat.png", if I enter "folder/images/" it gives me:

> 403 Forbidden nginx/1.11.8

How can I download or see all the files within the folder directory without having to go directly to the image included at the end of the directory website link? (Such as "folder/images/cat.png")

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nginx config file:

```
location /path-to-folder {
    autoindex on;
}
```

Make sure there's no index file in the folder you want to view already e.g. index.html/php.

You'll need to have HttpAutoindexModule enabled.

You can also do this on Apache web servers by putting an .htaccess file in the directory you want to view:

```
Options +Indexes
```